# Apple's iCloud blocking emails from my website

Tags: email, iis, icloud

I am working on a web application, and am having trouble with the most basic of functions, sending an email. My email code does work, I can send to gmail, yahoo, and my work email address all day long. The problem is that when ever the web application attempts to send to an Apple iCloud email address, the email never makes it. I've checked the email server logs, and it does send, which would lead me to believe that Apple is somehow blocking my emails before they ever reach the user.

System Setup

- Domain name purchased through GoDaddy. I set up a DNS A record to forward all traffic that hits that domain name to our virtual server, which is hosted at 1and1
- The virtual server is a windows 2008 server. I set it up as an email server that actually sends the email itself, as opposed to relaying through GoDaddy.
  Note: on the above, all i did was add a *. entry in the iis email configuration

Below is my PHP test code, that sends to every where with no problems, except iCloud.

```
mail("person@me.com", "test", "this is a plain test", 'From: Site <no-    reply@domainname.com>');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After talking to one of our in house sys admins, he mentioned that I might need to have a reverse DNS record setup for the virtual server. I have submitted a ticket to have this one, and will report back. (I'm a dev, not a sys admin, so this is all new to me)

Comment: Okay. We finished the rDNS record for the server's IP address, but it would appear that apple is still blocking simple test emails. :( I'm now out of ideas, and help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Got it working finally. For some reason Apple had our server's IP on a blacklist. Submitted a request to have our IP removed from the blacklist and all is well

Comment: How did you contact Apple? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: How to contact Apple about this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204137

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a reverse DNS entry added for our server's IP address, and got the server's IP address taken off of Apple's blacklist.